# Determining line of intersection from homography matrix

Tags: computer-vision, homography

I have two planes in 3D space that intersect (along a 3D line, naturally). Furthermore, I have established a 2D coordinate system on each plane and have computed the 3x3 homography matrix H representing a projective mapping between these coordinates.

Question: is there a way to determine the line of intersection of the two planes in the 2D coordinate system of each plane, using only H?

I reason that the transformation y=H*x must be length-preserving on the line of intersection, but that does not appear to be enough to determine the line uniquely.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Reformulate in the way that we have: Hx=x, where x = (x1, x2, 1), H = {hij}.

You need to find the solution of system (H-I)x = 0. So task is to find the kernel of following matrix, for solve it you can use SVD (or standard functions). That helps you to find 3d-line of intersection if it exists. Suppose that nullspace represents with vector C.

For 2d-line: you may retrieve two points from that vector (e.g. zero and C) and translate it into plane coordinate system

Comment: Thanks for replying. However I don't see how the null space of H-I can tell me the 3D representation of the intersection line, if that's what you're claiming. The line of intersection is uniquely determined by the planes. However, there are many possible choices of 2D coordinate systems in each plane, each giving rise to a different H with a different null space for H-I. Is there a literature source that you are taking this from?